# 'Obsessiveness about' or 'obsessiveness with'

Tags: prepositions, nouns, collocations, post-modifier

I was wondering whether A or B are grammatically correct:

A: obsessiveness **about**

B: obsessiveness **with**

or maybe even a completely different preposition is necessary here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think "obsessiveness with" is more correct, even though I don't think in the dialect and academic writing, people will often use the word "obsessiveness"

Answer (score 1):

1. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/obsessive

> obsessive about (doing) something
>
> I try to stay fit, but I’m not obsessive about it.

2. https://linggle.com/?q=obsessiveness+about%2Fwith